Use Python interpreter with modified File Capabilities (CAP_NET_ADMIN)
Background
I've added the NET_CAP_ADMIN to my Python interpreter (/usr/bin/python3.8) with # setcap cap_net_admin+ep /usr/bin/python3.8. Unfortunately, this causes ROS2 to throw an error when I get the "Import failing" error, which, among other libraries, for example fails to import /opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/_rclpy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so. When I remove the capability with #setcap -r /usr/bin/python3.8, ROS2 works again, and this Github Issue comment seems to confirm that the capability changed the interpreter, and caused the problem.
My question is whether I can somehow rebuild or reinstall ROS2 to use the Python interpreter with this additional file capability.
